# How can I redirect a subdomain to a specific URL?

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, redirect, iirf

I am updating the Iirf.ini file to redirect *sub.columbia.edu* to *giving.columbia.edu*/**video**.

*sub.columbia.edu* is already redirecting to *giving.columbia.edu*.
How can I go one step further to redirect it to *giving.columbia.edu*/**video**.

Important Note: I would like the URL to show as *sub.columbia.edu* in the browser and not as *giving.columbia.edu*/**video**

```
#Redirect subdomain to specific URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.columbia\.edu
RewriteRule ^/$ /video
```

The above doesn't work. Any ideas how I should modify this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? in the root of sub.columbia.edu?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.columbia\.edu
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://giving.columbia.edu/video [L,R=301]
```

Or you can do a redirect, this should work also.

```
Redirect 301 / http://giving.columbia.edu/video
```

Comment: Thank you - it is adding 'http://' in front of the URL but not the '/video' I also updated the question to remove the .htaccess tag - I first was updating this file until I realized it was using IIS - I am now updating an iirf.ini file instead.

Comment: This won't work with IIS. I do not know IIS well enough for rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for misleading you!